# How to replace a specific character in a string along with the immediate next character

Tags: ruby, regex, string

I have a string of text:

```
string = "%hello %world ho%w is i%t goin%g"
```

I want to return the following:

```
"Hello World hoW is iT goinG
```

The `%` sign is a key that tells me the next character should be capitalized. The closest I have gotten so far is:

```
@thing = "%this is a %test this is %only a %test"

if @thing.include?('%')
  indicator_position = @thing.index("%")
  lowercase_letter_position = indicator_position + 1
  lowercase_letter = @thing[lowercase_letter_position]

  @thing.gsub!("%#{lowercase_letter}","#{lowercase_letter.upcase}")
end
```

This returns:

```
"This is a Test this is %only a Test"
```

It looks like I need to iterate through the string to make it work as it is only replacing the lowercase 't' but I can't get it to work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this with `gsub` and a block:

```
string.gsub(/%(.)/) do |m|
  m[1].upcase
end
```

Using a block allows you to run arbitrary code on each match.

Comment: thanks you kind stranger. I really need to familiarize myself with the regex in the gsub. If anyone has a resource that explains it well please let me know. This is such a time saver.

Comment: Regular expressions can get kind of crazy, but there's a lot of guides on how to understand and use them more effectively. You might want [a book](http://regex.info) as a solid reference.

Comment: Backslash before percent sign is redundant, as well as block variable: `.gsub(/%(.)/) { $1.upcase }` or `.gsub(/%./) { $&[-1].upcase }`.

Comment: @mudasobwa `$1` is not always the best plan, it can change if you do other matches, so using your match object is preferable. You're right about `%` being okay unescaped.

Comment: @LuigiAversano http://www.regular-expressions.info/ might be a good online start.

Answer (score 1):

Inferior to @tadman, but you could write:

```
string.gsub(/%./, &:upcase).delete('%')
  #=> "Hello World hoW is iT goinG
```

Comment: `.gsub(/(?<=%)./, &:upcase).delete('%')` Even more: lookbehind is sorta superfluous, since you are deleting `%`s afterwards: `.gsub(/%./, &:upcase).delete('%')`.

Comment: @mudasobwa, many thanks for your excellent suggestion. I've edited my answer and put it in my memory bank. (Readers: I previously had `string.gsub(/(?<=%)./) { |s| s.upcase }.delete('%')`, `(?<=%)` being a positive lookbehind).